# react radio button doesn't work on the first click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a radio button using pure css, but it doesn't work on first click, it only work on the second click onward, not sure it has to do with my react prop or not:

```
const Radio = ({ id, name, value, checked, children }) => (
  <div className="radioBtn">
    <input type="radio" value={value} id={id} name={name} checked={checked} />
    <label className={"radio"} htmlFor={id}>
      <span className={"big"}>
        <span className={"small"} />
      </span>
      <span>{children}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sass-34b8w

Comment: Did you read the error: `Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a 'checked' prop to a form field without an 'onChange' handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use 'defaultChecked'. Otherwise, set either 'onChange' or 'readOnly'`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `defaultChecked` instead of `checked={checked}`.